# C Program ERROR 2440/2447 in my code works on online commpiler but not in visual studios 2019

Tags: arrays, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

my program works on all online compilers but not on visual studios. However whenever I try to run it on visual studios 2019, it doesn't run and gives me 2 errors. error2440 and error2447. I have tried to fix it but nothing seems to work if anyone has any idea on what to do it would be appreciated the code:

EDIT: after putting const in front of char I did not get any errors but I did get multiple warnings. the warnings are:

warning C4101: 'year': unreferenced local variable
warning C4101: 't': unreferenced local variable
warning C4101: 'r': unreferenced local variable
warning C4101: 'weekdays': unreferenced local variable
warning C4101: 'leapyear': unreferenced local variable
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'year' used
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'firstday' used
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'p' used
error C4716: 'printday': must return a value
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'year' used

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int month_days[] = { 0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
char* month_name[] =
{
" ",
"\n\n\n\t\t1",
"\n\n\n\t\t2",
"\n\n\n\t\t3",
"\n\n\n\t\t4",
"\n\n\n\t\t5",
"\n\n\n\t\t6",
"\n\n\n\t\t7",
"\n\n\n\t\t8",
"\n\n\n\t\t9",
"\n\n\n\t\t10",
"\n\n\n\t\t11",
"\n\n\n\t\t12"
};
int get_first_start_day(int year)
{
int start_day;
int x, y, z;

x = (year - 1) / 4;
y = (year - 1) / 100;
z = (year - 1) / 400;
start_day = (year + x - y + z) % 7;
return start_day;
}

void set_feb_days(int year)
{
if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)
    month_days[2] = 29;
else
    month_days[2] = 28;
}

void display_month_calendar(int days, int start_day)
{
int month, year;
for (month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
{
    printf("%s", month_name[month]);
    printf("\n\nSun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n");

    for (days = 1; days <= 1 + start_day * 5; days++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (days = 1; days <= month_days[month]; days++)
    {
        printf("%2d", days);
        if ((days + start_day) % 7 > 0)
            printf("   ");
        else
            printf("\n ");
    }
    start_day = (start_day + month_days[month]) % 7;
  }
}
int printday(void)
{
int month[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
char week[7][10];
int date, mon, year, i, t, r, s = 0;
strcpy(week[0], "Sunday");
strcpy(week[1], "Monday");
strcpy(week[2], "Tuesday");
strcpy(week[3], "Wednesday");
strcpy(week[4], "Thursday");
strcpy(week[5], "Friday");
strcpy(week[6], "Saturday");
printf("Please Enter the date and month:  ");
scanf("%d%d", &date, &mon);
if ((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
    month[1] = 29;
for (i = 0; i < mon - 1; i++)
    s = s + month[i];
s = s + (date + year + (year / 4) - 2);
s = s % 7;
printf("\n%d/%d is a %s\n", date, mon, week[s]);
}
void occurrenceDays(int p, char firstday)
{
int year;
int monthdays[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
firstday = get_first_start_day(year);
char days[7][10];
strcpy(days[0], "Sunday");
strcpy(days[1], "Monday");
strcpy(days[2], "Tuesday");
strcpy(days[3], "Wednesday");
strcpy(days[4], "Thursday");
strcpy(days[5], "Friday");
strcpy(days[6], "Saturday");
int count[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    count[i] = 4;
int pos;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (firstday == days[i][10])
    {
        pos = i;
        break;
    }
}
int inc = monthdays[p] - 28;
for (int i = pos; i < pos + inc; i++)
{
    if (i > 6)
        count[i % 7] = 5;
    else
        count[i] = 5;
}
int weekdays = monthdays[p] - count[0] - count[6];
printf("Their are %d sundays,%d Saturdays and %d weekdys in the month\n", count[0], count[6], 
weekdays);
}

int main(void)
{
int year, start_day, leapyear, t, p, firstday, weekdays;
int month;
printf("Please Enter a Four Digit Year : ");
scanf("%d", &year);
start_day = get_first_start_day(year);
set_feb_days(year);
display_month_calendar(year, start_day);
printf("\n");
printf("Please Enter the Starting Day of the year (1=Sun, 7=Sat): 6 ");
printf("Please enter the month : ");
scanf("%d", &month);
occurrenceDays(p, firstday);
printday();
printf("Do you want to try it again?(1 to continue/0 to quit) :");
scanf("%d", &t);
while (t >= 0)
{
    if (t == 1)
    {
        printday();
        printf("Do you want to try it again?(1 to continue/0 to quit) :");
        scanf("%d", &t);
    }
    else
    {
    }
    break;
}
return 0;
}
```

however my error is here:

```
{
" ",
"\n\n\n\t\t1",
"\n\n\n\t\t2",
"\n\n\n\t\t3",
"\n\n\n\t\t4",
"\n\n\n\t\t5",
"\n\n\n\t\t6",
"\n\n\n\t\t7",
"\n\n\n\t\t8",
"\n\n\n\t\t9",
"\n\n\n\t\t10",
"\n\n\n\t\t11",
"\n\n\n\t\t12"
};
```

thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67189119/edit) the post to include the exact and complete error msgs as shown in Visual Studio. Also, please tag only C or C++ as they are different languages which can affect the answer. In fact you may be compiling this as C++ code when you are intending it to be C code.

Comment: Your code has other issues as well, but in this case you cannot assign string constants to a non-const char pointer. Change `char* month_name[]` to `const char* month_name[]`

Comment: Post your bug also.

Comment: @hedayatullah sarwary I posted the warnings in the edit